# How to get total count of TypeScript errors for whole project?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm working on a team project using TypeScript, and I know for a fact that there's literally 100s of TypeScript errors (I see them in the TypeScript tool window in PhpStorm).

I'm trying to use `tsc` to get the error count, but it's only reporting 46...

```
tsc

...

Found 46 errors.
```

And they're all from node_modules, even though that's excluded in our `tsconfig.json` file.

No idea why it is scanning `node_modules`, or why it's saying there's only 46 errors total for the whole project.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the fix was simply to run:

```
npx tsc
```

...so maybe the differences were down to different versions of TypeScript?...

My global version:

```
tsc --version
Version 3.3.3333
```

My project version:

```
npx tsc --version
Version 3.7.5
```

I still don't understand why there would be such a huge difference between 3.3.3333 and 3.7.5 though?  And why the older version would have been looking in `node_modules`?